# TP-link w8968 Connection issues

Tags: router

I am facing a wierd issue. It is that my router keeps dropping connection with the devices.

Details: I keep a tab in laptop for Tp link home page which keeps on refreshing in a while. Many of the times it does not open until I disconnect network and reconnect. As soon as I reconnect it starts working for some time.

Please guide me if I am doing anything wrong.